# Проблема redirect

Tags: регулярные-выражения, .htaccess, redirect

На сайте написан redirect всех pdf файлов из корня сайта в директорию **docs**

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+).pdf /docs/$1.pdf [R=301,L]
```

Однако, в **docs** есть папка **pdf** и любой запрос, например `site.com/docs/pdf/qwerty.pdf`, делает редирект на `site.com/docs/docs.pdf`

Как сделать исключение на данную папку?

Comment: Попробуйте создать в папке `docs` файл `.htaccess` с единственной строчкой `RewriteEngine Off`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Помогло, спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создайте в папке `docs` новый файл `.htaccess` с единственной строчкой

```
RewriteEngine Off
```

Answer (score 2):

У вас условие в редиректе неверное: точка может быть любым символом, если она не экранирована и не указан якорь конца строки. Делайте так:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)\.pdf$ /docs/$1.pdf [R=301,L]
```